# Aggregate lists using stream api

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

If you have

```
class C1{
public List<C2> c2list;
}

class C2{
public List<C3> c3list;
}
```

then you want to write a method, that given a list of C1, it will aggregate all the C3s that are in the list of C1s.

```
public List<C3> getThemll(List<C1> list) {
     list.stream.map(a->a.c2list)
                .map(b->b.c3list)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is not giving me a `List<C3>`, but a `List<List<C3>>`. I'm also not sure if its aggregating all the C3s for every C2.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should take a look at `flatMap()`

Comment: exactly that, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
public List<C3> getThemll(List<C1> list) {
     list.stream.flatmap(a->a.c2list.stream())
                .flatmap(b->b.c3list..stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

this does the trick, thanks

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comments, here a full example showing how to ***flatten out a stream*** of streams to a stream of an object (known as ***Stream concatenation***):
The title should be edited to "***Merge Streams***" or "***Concatenate lists***"

```
  public class Community {

    private List<Person> persons;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

--

```
  public class Person {

    private List<Address> addresses;
      
    // Constructors, getters and setters

  }
```

--

```
 public class Address {

    private String city;

    // Constructors, getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "city='" + city + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
  }
```

Demo:

```
public class AggregationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Community> communities = List.of(
                new Community(List.of(new Person(List.of(new Address("Paris"))))),
                new Community(List.of(new Person(List.of(new Address("Florence"))))));

        List<Address> addresses = communities.stream()
                .flatMap(community -> community.getPersons().stream())
                .flatMap(person -> person.getAddresses().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<List<Person>> collectedListOfList = communities.stream()
                .map(community -> community.getPersons())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        addresses.forEach(System.out::println);
        collectedListOfList.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
```

}

Output:

```
Person{addresses=[Address{city='Paris'}]}
Person{addresses=[Address{city='Florence'}]}

[Person{addresses=[Address{city='Paris'}]}]
[Person{addresses=[Address{city='Florence'}]}]
```